# Does std::condition_variable::wait_until have any advantage against std::this_thread::sleep_for?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In a time waiting scenario:

> our software works in the background, and synchronizes data with the
>   server in every 20 - 30 minutes.

I wanted to use

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for
```

But my superior strongly against any form of sleep function. He recommends

```
std::condition_variable::wait_until(lock, timeout-time, pred)
```

I wonder if there are any disadvantage for sleep_for under such scenario?

Comment: what is "such scenario"? The two typically are used in quite different scenarios

Comment: `condition_variable` can *wake* sooner than the timeout.

Comment: In the 2. example, do you use this lock for anything else ? What about the predicate - do you want to use that too so you could wake up earlier than the timeout ?

Comment: if you want to sleep unconditionally take 1, if you want to wait for a condition AND limited to a timeout than use 2. Both are totally different scenarios. There is no use 2 for 1 because it is "better". It feels like "use a for loop statement always, even if you only want the if clause of it.

Comment: You haven't said what you were going to use these for.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, our software works in the background, and  synchronizes data with the server in every 20 - 30 minutes. Here's a problem, if the user changes the config, we may need to stop the timer and re-schedule it.

Comment: With a condition variable you can wake up the thread when you receive data from the server, for example. Also, if you sleep for 20min straight you can get problems when shutting down the application (as you cannot wake the thread up to properly exit the function if you use `sleep_for`).

Comment: @Timo, yes, I can see the point now, condition variable allows user to cancel or re-schedule the timer.:)

Comment: @Timo thats an answer, no?

Comment: This incorrectly stated question, it has similar to [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why do you think you code needs to use `sleep_for()`?  How can you know that your code has slept for enough time?  What do you do if it hasn't?

Comment: If the timing is very short duration and critical, I favor condition_variable.  For 20 minutes the exact timing is probably not so critical, in which case I don't have a problem with sleep, but I would put a much shorter duration sleep (maybe 500ms) in a loop and count to 20 minutes.  This way you don't lose control of the thread for 20 minutes at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already, it depends only on your usecase. The main difference between the two is, that `condition_variable` **can** wake up earlier if you trigger it. You also can add a predicate that must be satisfied in order to actually wake up, but that's only a quality of life addition. And btw, the equivalent to `sleep_for` is `wait_for` and not `wait_until`. `condition_variable` is also great to communicate or synchronize between multiple threads.

Given everything you said, I would use `condition_variable` for the following reasons:

1. Putting a thread to sleep for longer periods of time is not a good idea because your application can exit at any time (or rather can be requested to exit). In that case you probably want your thread to exit properly, so you have to be able to wake it up at any time.
2. You want to change the config on the fly. If your thread has to restart with new parameters or if you need that thread to actually load the config file you also don't want to wait for the next 20min intervall to end.